# Pyautogui press keyboard and mouse same time

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

i'm developing a pyautogui program in a game and need to press CTRL + MouseLeftButton

```
pyautogui.press('ctrl')
pyautogui.click()
```

can you help me to do this at the same time

I know that I can do 2 press in keyboard using

```
pyautogui.press('key1', 'key2')
```

but cant find how to do this with mouse and keyboard

Answer (score -1):

You can use `threading` to do both things at the same time.

Snippet of code:

```
from threading import Thread
import pyautogui

def press():
    pyautogui.press('ctrl')

def click():
    pyautogui.click()

Thread(target = press).start()
Thread(target = click).start()
```

and this might work. I do know that there is something going on with the `multiprocessing` module, but I don't know how to use it, but it might be useful for you to check it out.